# Imprimir dos listas como columnas con tkinter en un frame

Tags: python, tkinter

Recién comienzo con Python y tkinter quisiera saber si se puede hacer y si es posible me guíen como o donde conseguir una respuesta de lo siguiente. Genero dos listas y quiero imprimirlas en forma vertical una a lado de la otra y separadas por una linea en un frame o en una ventana. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justamente hago eso en uno de mis programas! Aquí el código super simplificado:

Primero, dos listas para guardar los `Labels` (son objetos Tkinter que sirven para mostrar texto)

```
columnaA = []
columnaB = []
```

Luego, la función que nos deja añadir un nuevo `Label` a estas listas. Toma como parámetros un `master` (que será el objeto donde se guarde cada Label. Puede ser un `Frame`, un `LabelFrame`, o el mismo `Tk`), luego `it1` e `it2`, que deben ser texto - `str`.

```
def agregarColumna(master,it1,it2):
    columnaA.append(Label(master,text=it1))
    columnaB.append(Label(master,text=it2))
```

La función `actualizarColumnas()` la uso para insertar cada label de las listas creadas al principio en el widget maestro.

```
def actualizarColumnas():
    for i, entry in enumerate(columnaA):
        entry.grid(row=i, column=0)
    for i, combobox in enumerate(columnaB):
        combobox.grid(row=i, column=1)
```

Y en realidad, eso sería todo, y para crear la ventana, solo sería:

```
itemsA = ['Hola','Test']
itemsB = ['Hola2','Test2']

a = Tk()
for it1, it2 in itemsA, itemsB: #Por cada item en estas listas...
    agregarColumna(a,it1,it2)
a.mainloop()
```

Ojo que para que funcione bien, ambas listas deben tener el mismo tamaño, sino puedes usar `itertools.zip_longest(itemsA, itemsB)` (luego de importar el paquete, claro) en lugar de solo `itemsA, itemsB`.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme. Clarisimos tu explicacion. Creo que es lo que estoy buscando. Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guiarte del siguiente ejemplo:

```
u=["a","b","c","d","e"]
v=[11,15,16,14,15]
for i in range(len(u)):
    print(f"u: {u[i]}  , v: {v[i]}")
```

cuya salida es:

```
     u: a  , v: 11
     u: b  , v: 15
     u: c  , v: 16
     u: d  , v: 14
     u: e  , v: 15
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y por tu respuesta. Una pregunta la salida de este ejemplo no es por consola?

Comment: @Dan sí lo es, no debí poner los `>>>>`